# document.activeElement doesn't work as expected on Chrome, what are the alternatives?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Hi,

I want to check/uncheck all the checkboxes with the same class as well as disable\enable the associated text fields when checking/unchecking a checkbox.

I managed to write a code using `document.activeElement` and `document.getElementsByClassName` that'll do exactly that, except that it doesn't work on Chrome. It's a [reported bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89708) that it returns body instead of the actual activeElement unless the activeElement is a text field.

Is there a workaround that I can use until the bug is fixed?

[My code:](http://jsbin.com/oriseb/3/edit)

JS:

```
function changeAll(variable) {
    var current = document.activeElement;
    var checkboxes = variable + "_g";
    var text = variable + "_v";
    var i;
    if (current.checked === true) {
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName(checkboxes).length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(checkboxes)[i].checked = true;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName(text).length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(text)[i].disabled = false;
        }
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName(checkboxes).length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(checkboxes)[i].checked = false;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName(text).length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(text)[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="y_g" onClick="changeAll('y')">
<input type="text" class="y_v" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" class="y_g" onClick="changeAll('y')">
<input type="text" class="y_v" disabled>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="x_g" onClick="changeAll('x')">
<input type="text" class="x_v" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" class="x_g" onClick="changeAll('x')">
<input type="text" class="x_v" disabled>
```

Comment: Don't use inline event handler attributes! Then you would not need `activeElement` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the reference

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="y_g" onClick="changeAll(this,'y')">
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeAll(current, variable) {
    //var current = document.activeElement;
```

ideally you would not be using inline events.