# Checkboxes do not receive the focus when clicked on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, checkbox, focus

I just came across another strange behaviour on Chrome: when you click a checkbox or its label, the checkbox does not receive the focus (instead the body takes the focus).

This behaviour can be observed here: http://jsfiddle.net/YfbR7/7/ (`see code sample here`)

Is there any workaround to make the checkbox receive the focus, like on the other browsers?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357877/document-activeelement-doesnt-work-as-expected-on-chrome-what-are-the-alternat and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=169253

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve it like this

```
$(function () {
   $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (event) {
      $(this).parent().css("background", "red");
   });                        
})
```

Comment: Yes, this is the least worse way I have found. But I can't take it as an answer as the focus transfers to the body for a short while (that would be enough to break codes that monitor the focus on the page)

Comment: Alternatively, it is also possible to move the focus to the checkbox, on mouse down, **after a timeout** to emulate the behaviour of other browsers: 

`$("input[type=checkbox],label").on("mousedown", function (event) {
      var el = $(this); 
      setTimeout(function () { el.focus() }, 0);
   });`

As demonstrated here http://jsfiddle.net/YfbR7/13/ this is still not good enough because the body will receive the focus for a short while.

Comment: Truthfully I have no idea how you could go around this without ugly hacks in code. Its webkit bug which they didn't solve yet.
Does it really matter if body is focused first?

Comment: I am developing a dropdown menu which closes when its content losing the focus. So yes, it is an issue in that context. I was able to work around the problem, but I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I understand the frustration all you can do is subscribe to their bug issue and wait and hope that someday this will be fixed so that you have a clean code. :)